# Matching response to multiple ranges of figures

Tags: ruby, functional-programming, logic

I have a method that will return a number between 1 - 100

depending on whether the response (x) is between
100 - 90 i would like one response, 89 - 85 another 84 - 72 another ... etc

I use

```
if x > 90
 response a
elsif x > 85
 response b
elsif etc...
```

but this seems a little messy, is there a better way of refactoring this?

Many thanks.

Comment: "response X" are code (imperative code) or expressions?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com would be the appropriate place for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take advantage of [`Range#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) and use a `case` statement:

```
case x
when 72..84
  # Do something
when 85..89
  # Do something
when 90..100
  # Do something
else
  # Do something when no matches
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try a table (a `Hash`) where the keys are ranges and the values ar the numbers you want to return :

```
T = { 
  (90..100) => 1,
  (85..89) => 2,
  # and so on
}

(r,v) = T.find {|r,v| r.member? x}

if v then 
  return v
else
  # x wasn't in any of the defined ranges
end
```

Comment: +1 I would write the code somewhat differently (with a Facets' map_detect, I don't think the OP needs to know the range key), but a hash of `{Range => value}` is the simplest way to go.

Comment: What I meant was: `value = T.map_detect { |range, v| v if range.include?(x) } || default_value`.

Comment: It seems to me that the `case` statement in Andrew Marshall's response is a clearer way to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @Eric: A `case` is also good, but it's more verbose. I think it depends on the nature of the values, if they are simple expressions, a hash is just ok. Otherwise, use a case.

Comment: This code will also work with an array of arrays (e.g. `[[90..100, 1], [85..89, 2]]`

Comment: @tokland: Makes sense.  Also, when I think more about it, it occurs to me that hashes are good for dynamic dispatch.